# solutions of $\bar z = |z-2\Im(z)|^2$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I need to find all the solutions of $\bar z = |z-2\Im(z)|^2$.

I know that $z=x+iy$ and $\bar z=x-iy$ and then $2\Im(z)=2y$. But can someone show the algebra for what I do next?

Comment: Please use MathJAX to typeset your post, to make it more readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the right side of $\bar z = |z-2\Im(z)|^2$ is a real number, so we should have $y=0$ for $z=x+iy$ on the left side. Now, the equation will be $x=|x|^2$ with the only answers of $x=0,1$.

Answer (score 4):

You get by your ideas that
$$\overline z = \vert z - \Im(z)\vert^2 \iff
x - iy = \vert x + iy - 2y\vert^2$$ and hence
$$x - iy = (x - 2y)^2 + y^2.$$
By comparing these terms you get that $y = 0$ and it follows by substitution that $x = x^2$. Hence you have $x \in \{0, 1\}$ and $y = 0$. So as your solution you have $z \in \{0 ,1\}$.
Please check my answer if you are satisfied with it :)

Comment: Its that easy??

Comment: Yes, it is :) Since $\vert z \vert^2 = x^2 + y^2$, when $z = x + iy$. Please don't forget to accept my answer :)